# Выражение со смыслом "оба варианта плохие"

Tags: фразеология

Здравствуйте! Ищу поговорку или разговорное выражение, как ответ в диалоге на ситуацию, в которой оба варианта, предложенные собеседником, никуда не годятся. Единственное, что пришло на ум пока - матерный интернет-мем "Эскобара" (прошу прощения, цитировать не буду, кто слышал, тот поймет :)), но мне нужно нормальное разговорное выражение без мата. Надеюсь на Вашу помощь.

Answer (score 2):

Хрен редьки не слаще, одно другого не лучше, одно другого стоит, всё одно, нет никакой разницы.

Что так, что эдак.

Answer (score 1):

Что в лоб, что по лбу. Не вмер Данила, болячка задавила. 
Если ситуация развивается, "из огня да в полымя".

Answer (score 0):

Пардон, а разве не "оба варианта плохИ"? (заместо плохИЕ)

Answer (score -1):

Зависит от того, с кам диалог ведёте: ежели с "проффесором" лингвистики, тогда ответы 1 и 2. Если в курилке с приятелями, тогда варианты вроде "однох--ственно, одночленственно, монопенисуально" или "что пнём по сове, что совой по пню", "те же яйца - вид сбоку" ну и наконец: "в сортах говна не силён".

Comment: Автор вопроса просил  "нормальное разговорное выражение **без мата**"